# Trying to select radio button with Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I am trying to select a radio button which i have done on other pages but cant seem to get this one to work

Here is the html for the radio button I am trying to access:

```
<fieldset id="category_fieldset">

<div class="group category first">
    <label class="label"></label>
    <div id="category_options">
        <div class="toggle-btn">
            <input id="category_rental" type="radio" value="rental" name="fields[category]"></input>
            <label for="category_rental">
                <span></span>
                For Rent
            </label>
```

Here are the --- i have made (none of these have worked)

```
browser.radio(:name => "fields[category]").set

browser.radio(:id => "category_rental").click

browser.radio(:value => "rental").click
```

Comment: When you say "cant seem to get this one to work"...is there an error?  Often, these problems are either due to dynamic content that hasn't fully loaded or due to an <iframe>.   You could try `browser.radio(:id => "category_rental").when_present.click` and `browser.iframe.radio(:id => "category_rental").click` respectively.

Comment: here is the error I am receiving .rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:132:in `click'
 from postlets.rb:33:in `<main>'

Comment: It might not have loaded at the time you try to set, Can you execute b.radio().exists?to confirm that radio button exist or loaded?

Comment: Also there could be another element that is intercepting the click.  Does the html look any different for this one?

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments.  Instead, edit your original post with the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the feedback on this

i tried this and seems to work

```
browser.label(:text => "For Rent").click
```